# How do I add a class to the admin page in django python?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I am currently making a small site in django. When I tried to add a button to the admin page using this code:

```
 from django.contrib import admin

 # Register your models here.
  from .models import profile

 class profileAdmin(admin.Modeladmin):
      class Meta: 
           Model =  profile
 admin.site.register(profile, profileAdmin)
```

That is the code to add the button to the admin page.

```
 from django.db import models

 # Create your models here.
class profile(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
      desc = models.TextField(default = 'default user description')
      job = models.CharField(max_length=20)

      def _unicode_(self):
          return self.name
```

That is the code for the button. I also know that the profile app which contains this button and admin page has been added to the install apps and is functioning. When I try to makemigrations I am prompted with this error.

AttributeError: module 'django.contrib.admin' has no attribute 'Modeladmin'

Comment: Case is important; it's `ModelAdmin`, not `Modeladmin`.

Comment: Thank you that did fix the error however now I have another error, line 9, in profileAdmin
    admin.site.register(profile, profileadmin)
NameError: name 'profileadmin' is not defined. any fixes? Nevermind I fixed therror thank you for your help!